# algorithm combination that gets us closest to 1000

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want the combination that gets me closest to 1000 by adding the numbers together.

those are my numbers {500,498,4,900, 4}

like this: 500 + 498 = 998  which is just 2 away from 1000 and like this 500 + 498 + 4 = 1002  which is also 2 away.

i'm trying to do something like this

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 4, 900, 500, 498, 4 };
        int number = 1000;
        int closest = list.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(number - item)).First();
        Console.WriteLine(closest);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

but I think I doing it in a wrong way!

what you suggest? How do I solve it.

Comment: ...not very helpful, I suggest you add a little more detail on what's happening.

Comment: I get this messege "Unable to retrieve property split for a reference that is undefined or null"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum).

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your for loop. There is an extra semicolon.

you have:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < splitnamn.length - 1; i++); {
```

should be:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < splitnamn.length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: i get this messege "Unable to retrieve property split for a reference that is undefined or null"